# How to prove $26|m \leftrightarrow 2|m \land 13|m$. $m \in \mathbb {Z}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Prove, that $26|m \leftrightarrow 2|m \land 13|m$. $m \in \mathbb {Z}$

**My progress:** I know that $\exists k \in \mathbb {Z}, m = 26k$, $\exists l \in \mathbb {Z}, m = 13l$, $\exists n \in \mathbb {Z}, m = 13n$, but I don't know how to connect the dots and prove the logical biconditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking too hard.  Also, you're making your life harder by trying to speak only in symbols.  Use some words. :-)

First: suppose that $26\mid m$.  Then there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m=26k$.  But, then we can write $m=13(2k)$, so that $13\mid m$; and, we can write $m=2(13k)$, so that $2\mid m$.

On the other hand, suppose $2\mid m$ AND $13\mid m$.  As $13\mid m$, we can write $m=13k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Now, $2$ is prime, and therefore $2\mid 13k$ if and only if $2\mid 13$ or $2\mid k$.  Clearly, $2$ doesn't divide $13$; so, we must have $2\mid k$, and therefore $k=2h$ for some $h\in\mathbb{Z}$.  But, this means that we can write $m=13k=13(2h)=26h$, so that $26\mid m$ as claimed.

Comment: "You may be thinking too hard. Also, you're making your life harder by trying to speak only in symbols. Use some words."  THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: I suppose a sentence here or there wouldn't do any harm :3.